# Reverse Proxy in SSL Config in XAMPP not working

Tags: reactjs, node.js, apache, ssl, xampp

I am having an issue with the SSL configuration. I have installed a valid SSL certificate on my EC2 instance as well. I want to run a react and node application using XAMPP. They run on SSL individually but they are not running simultaneously.

I have done the following steps-

1. Installed XAMPP on an ec2 instance
2. Uploaded the certificate key, crt and bundle in the config of XAMPP(httpd-ssl.conf).
3. Setup my nodejs to listen to port 3000 and enable the ssl.
4. Deploying my react frontend to htdocs for it to be accessible through https.

Below is my httpd-ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:/opt/lampp/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log"
TransferLog "/opt/lampp/logs/access_log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/lampp/apache2/conf/ssl/xyz.ca-bundle"
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
ProxyVia Full
<Proxy "*">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I am trying to run my node application on port 3000. The relevant lines on my nodejs is as follows -

```
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/xyz.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/xyz.pem')
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(3000, () => {};
```

Some of the errorlogs of https as follows -

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:36.803086 2023] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3299] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:36.940211 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3299] AH00163: Apache/2.4.56 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:36.940241 2023] [core:notice] [pid 3299] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.407513 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 3439] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1:3000) failed
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.407561 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3439] [client 106.222.201.230:16021] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.407645 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 3439] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1:3000) failed
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.407655 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3439] [client 106.222.201.230:16021] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.511170 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 3438] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1:3000) failed
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.511219 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3438] [client 106.222.201.230:6213] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: https://example.com/
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.511306 2023] [proxy:error] [pid 3438] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: http: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1:3000) failed
[Mon Dec 11 04:49:50.511316 2023] [proxy_http:error] [pid 3438] [client 106.222.201.230:6213] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1, referer: https://example.com/
```

When I remove the ProxyPass in the config and restart apache, the root application runs on https. When I add the ProxyPass and restart apache, then the node application runs on https but the root application(htdocs) does not.

I have tried all methods as shown in the forums as well and have run out of options.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)